# How to embed a picture link in python

Tags: python, image, embed

I am new to pyton and i want to prank my friends by make a specific picture to pop up. I have set up everything up but I don't understand how to open a picture link, like in javascript (I think). Any solution to this problem is acceptable!

Comment: Unfortunately SO is to help make people's code work, not to write it for them. As a newcomer to Python this might be a bit ambitious. Perhaps start by bringing up a browser window? https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing and it is more on the "can you code this for me" rather than you showing a problem you are having.
Nevertheless, a solution would be the following:

```
import os
from PIL import Image,ImageFont,ImageDraw
import time
import psutil
filedir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

while True:
    picture=Image.open(filedir+'/picture_name.jpeg')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(picture)

    picture.show()
    time.sleep(30)
    peicture.close()
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == "display":
            proc.kill()
    time.sleep(1200)
```

Now obviously for this you need to have the picture locally saved and know the path to it.

If you want to load one from the internet then I assume you could use

```
import urllib.request

url = urllib.request.urlopen('URL')
```

Or something of that form. I have never tried it.

Comment: I am just explaining why your question received negative feedback (-2 votes) from the community. Hope what I wrote helped in solving the problem. Good luck